# How to move the pointer of istream by n characters?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I would like to skip a few characters in a binary file between two istream getlines. What is the best way to do it?

Shell I just read into a dummy variable with istream::read?

Or shell I use n = istream::tellg and istream::seekg = n + 1000?

Comment: Just `seekg` from the current position, `std::ios::cur`.

Comment: @Kerrek: That should be answer. Post it as answer. You'll get reps ;-)

Comment: Yes, if I recall correctly, you can't rely on the number returned from `tellg` being meaningful in any way, and doing math on it and using the results in a subsequent `seekg` has undefined results. Turns out I'm wrong and am mixing up some facts about stdio with iostream.

Comment: @Nawaz: So it would seem, thanks! There's no underestimating upvotes ;-) (Sometimes I feel shy to post a one-line answer.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can simply move a stream position relative to the current position by using the `std::ios::cur` position argument:

```
std::ifstream f("myfile.txt");   // current position 0
f.seekg(200, std::ios::cur);     // relative seek
```

Negative values are also permitted. See e.g. [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/seekg/).