# Shouldn't I need to unget an istream before I clear it?

Tags: c++, string, iostream, cin

**Short Version of the Question**

If I'm reading in data like so:

```
    while (in >> x) {
      hw.push_back(x);
    }
    // clear the stream so that input will work for the next student
    in.clear();
```

where `in` is a `std::istream`, `x` is a `double` and `hw` is a `vector<double>`. Wouldn't I need to put back whatever read attempt caused me to break out of the while loop? Otherwise, wouldn't my next read from `in` skip some data?

**Full Question**

I'm trying to read from a text file that contains a string and a series of numbers. I'm processing this data into a struct which contains member attributes for this data.

The input data looks as follows:
`Moore 75 85 77 59 0 85 75 89`

This data represents a student's name, their final exam grade, their midterm exam grade, and some homework.

And to read such data in, I have the following:

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::istream;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::cin;

struct Student_info {
  std::string name;
  double midterm, final;
  std::vector<double> homework;
};

istream& read(istream&, Student_info&);
istream& read_hw(istream&, vector<double>&);

istream& read(istream& is, Student_info& s) {
  // Read and store th studen's name and midterm and final exam grades
  is >> s.name >> s.midterm >> s.final;

  read_hw(is, s.homework); // read and store all the student's homework grades
  return is;
}

istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& hw)
{
  if (in) {
    // get rid of previous contents
    hw.clear();

    // read homework grades
    double x;
    while (in >> x) {
      hw.push_back(x);
    }
    // clear the stream so that input will work for the next student
    in.clear();
  }
  return in;
}
```

In short, and if my understanding is correct, I first read the name, then two doubles (final and midterm exam) and then however many homeworks are present.

I know when to stop reading into a `vector<double>` of homework grades with the following:

```
    while (in >> x) {
      hw.push_back(x);
    }
    // clear the stream so that input will work for the next student
    in.clear();
```

This all looks perfectly sensible to me, but when I read in a series of data lines, the data does not get read in properly.

For example, with the following input:

```
Moo 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
Moore 75 85 77 59 0 85 75 89
Norman 57 78 73 66 78 70 88 89
```

I get the following output:

```
Name: Moo, Midterm: 100, Final: 100, Num HW: 6
Name: Moore, Midterm: 75, Final: 85, Num HW: 6
Name: orman, Midterm: 57, Final: 78, Num HW: 6
```

Notice the name is **orman**, NOT Norman. The *N* is missing. That's not a typo, that's the problem I'm trying to understand.

It would seem to me I need to "unget", though when I try to literally call `in.unget()` it doesn't improve things.

Below is some full input data and the complete source for a driver program if anyone wants to try this out in their hands:

**Full Input Data**

```
Moo 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
Moore 75 85 77 59 0 85 75 89
Norman 57 78 73 66 78 70 88 89
Olson 89 86 70 90 55 73 80 84
Peerson 47 70 82 73 50 87 73 71

Russel 72 87 88 54 55 82 69 87
Thomas 90 96 99 99 100 81 97 97
Vaughn 81 97 99 67 40 90 70 96
Westerly 43 98 96 79 100 82 97 96


Baker 67 72 73 40 0 78 55 70
Davis 77 70 82 65 70 77 83 81
Edwards 77 72 73 80 90 93 75 90
Franklin 47 70 82 73 50 87 73 71

Jones 77 82 83 50 10 88 65 80
Harris 97 90 92 95 100 87 93 91
Smith 87 92 93 60 0 98 75 90
Carpenter 47 90 92 73 100 87 93 91

Fail1 45 55 65 80 90 70 65 60
Fail2 55 55 65 50 55 60 65 60
```

**Full Source of Driver Program**

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::istream;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::cin;

struct Student_info {
  std::string name;
  double midterm, final;
  std::vector<double> homework;
};

istream& read(istream&, Student_info&);
istream& read_hw(istream&, vector<double>&);

istream& read(istream& is, Student_info& s) {
  // Read and store th studen's name and midterm and final exam grades
  is >> s.name >> s.midterm >> s.final;

  read_hw(is, s.homework); // read and store all the student's homework grades
  return is;
}

istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& hw)
{
  if (in) {
    // get rid of previous contents
    hw.clear();

    // read homework grades
    double x;
    while (in >> x) {
      hw.push_back(x);
    }
    // clear the stream so that input will work for the next student
    in.clear();
  }
  return in;
}

int main() {

  vector<Student_info> students;
  Student_info record;
  string::size_type maxlen = 0;

  while (read(cin, record)) {
    // find length of longest name
    cout << boost::format("Name: %1%, Midterm: %2%, Final: %3%, Num HW: %4%\n") % record.name % record.midterm % record.final % record.homework.size();
    students.push_back(record);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Using the full input data, the output looks like this (notice many names have been incorrectly):

```
Name: Moo, Midterm: 100, Final: 100, Num HW: 6
Name: Moore, Midterm: 75, Final: 85, Num HW: 6
Name: orman, Midterm: 57, Final: 78, Num HW: 6
Name: Olson, Midterm: 89, Final: 86, Num HW: 6
Name: rson, Midterm: 47, Final: 70, Num HW: 6
Name: Russel, Midterm: 72, Final: 87, Num HW: 6
Name: Thomas, Midterm: 90, Final: 96, Num HW: 6
Name: Vaughn, Midterm: 81, Final: 97, Num HW: 6
Name: Westerly, Midterm: 43, Final: 98, Num HW: 6
Name: ker, Midterm: 67, Final: 72, Num HW: 6
Name: vis, Midterm: 77, Final: 70, Num HW: 6
Name: wards, Midterm: 77, Final: 72, Num HW: 6
Name: ranklin, Midterm: 47, Final: 70, Num HW: 6
Name: Jones, Midterm: 77, Final: 82, Num HW: 6
Name: Harris, Midterm: 97, Final: 90, Num HW: 6
Name: Smith, Midterm: 87, Final: 92, Num HW: 6
Name: rpenter, Midterm: 47, Final: 90, Num HW: 6
Name: l1, Midterm: 45, Final: 55, Num HW: 6
Name: l2, Midterm: 55, Final: 55, Num HW: 6
```

**Update 1**

I tried adding `in.seekg(-1, in.cur);` after breaking out of the following while loop:

```
    double x;
    while (in >> x) {
      hw.push_back(x);
    }

    // Going to try and get the istream back to where it was when I broke out of the while loop.
    in.seekg(-1, in.cur);

    // clear the stream so that input will work for the next student
    in.clear();
```

Thinking this would take me back to whatever caused me to break out of the while loop. But still Student names are still not being read in correctly

**Update 2**

I see there is a nearly identical question here:

[Why is istream.clear() removing part of my strings while reading doubles and strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580400/why-is-istream-clear-removing-part-of-my-strings-while-reading-doubles-and-str?rq=1)

However the accepted solution does not explain **why** what is being done here is wrong -- it just offers a workaround.

**Update 3**

I appreciate all the workarounds, but consider this more focused question, why doesn't every subsequent line have a letter missing here or there? Only some lines do.

Comment: Reading/writing pushes the file pointer forward.

Comment: So when I exit the while loop because I read something that isn't a double, how do I move the file pointer back so that I can read the next line of data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move the pointer of istream by n characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403854/how-to-move-the-pointer-of-istream-by-n-characters)

Comment: Thanks Michael. It partially answers my question. But I am still a little baffled here as to whether this is the proper course of action. I see all over the web code similar to what I posted here -- A while loop that breaks when the istream returns False, and then calling `clear` on the istream. But I have not seen people move the pointer of the istream.

Comment: Generally you read from a stream when you know exactly what you will find based on the previous read. If you need some sort of parsing, you would first read it all in memory.

Comment: Because you know that a linebreak is the end of `Student_Info`, you can first read a line into a `std::string`, and then read the members from a `std::stringstream`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the weird extraction is that the letters `ABCDEFINP`  can occur in a `double`   and the others can't. See [strtof spec](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) for detail.

This is a fundamental problem with stream I/O without lookahead. The standard specifies (roughly speaking) that extraction continues until finding a character that can't occur in the destination type, and then try to convert what was extracted.  There have been various tweaks to the spec (including changing the list of valid characters for a double) over the years but no real solution.

There's no provision to put back characters on conversion failure , you will have to use a different extraction method.  As suggested in the other answer: since your input is line-oriented (i.e. newlines are significant) it would be good to use a line-oriented read function to read a line, and then parse a line.  Your method of using `>>` until error has no way of breaking at newlines (that operator treats all whitespace as identical).

Comment: Can you provide a link explaining what these characters mean in a `double`?

Comment: @EMiller OK, added link to strtof spec.  `0p` and `ABCDEF` are from base 16 format,  and there could be `INF` or `NAN`

Comment: Ah ha. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

There's usually no need to use `unget()` on standard streams. The problem you have is that you need to know when to stop reading a line. The function `std::getline` is made for this purpose. You can iterate through each line, store that line in a `std::istringstream`, and parse out the record from there:

```c++
std::istream& read_hw(std::istream& in, std::vector<double>& hw) {
  hw.clear();
  std::string line;
  if (std::getline(in, line)) {
    hw.assign(
      std::istream_iterator<double>{std::istringstream{line} >> std::skipws}, {}
    );
  }
  return in;
}
```